# Code first: One to many relationship of the same entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity `Product` which can have multiple additional products. So what I need is a junction table to map a `Product` to additional `Product`s.

What I tried to do is the following:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> AdditionalProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Add a collection of Products, hoping that EF would build a junction table. However I end up with this in my migration:

```
public partial class test1 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AddColumn("dbo.Product", "Product_Id", c => c.Int());
        CreateIndex("dbo.Product", "Product_Id");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Product_Id", "dbo.Product", "Id");
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Product", "Product_Id", "dbo.Product");
        DropIndex("dbo.Product", new[] { "Product_Id" });
        DropColumn("dbo.Product", "Product_Id");
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: One to many doesn't need a junction table, only many to many requires junction table.

Comment: @AliBahraminezhad how would you map one to many for the same entity without a junction table?

Comment: I do the same as what EF migration does in your example.

Comment: I want a list of additional products for the product. How does this help?

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani Can a product be the additional product of more than one product or to only one product at a time?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes a product can be an additional product to multiple products. And can also have its set of additional products.

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani then you will need to have a separate model class and table for Additional product which will contain the main `ProductId` and `AdditionalProductId` along with its primary key may called `Id`

Comment: @SanjnaMalpani Your project is on Entity Framework, not Entity Framework Core. isn't it?

Comment: @TanvirArjel yes its on EF not EF Core

Comment: Then follow my answer! It should work for you.

Answer (score 3):

As you said in the comment that:

> A product can be an additional product to multiple products. And can also have its set of additional products.

So, First make a model class named `AdditionalProduct` as follows:

```
[Table("AdditionalProduct")]
public class AdditionalProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int ProductId {get; set;}
    public int AdditionalProductId {get; set;}

    public Product Product {get; set;}
    public Product AdditionalProduct {get; set;}
}
```

And your `Product` class should as follows:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product : EntityBase
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    .......

    public virtual ICollection<AdditionalProduct> HisAdditionalProducts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AdditionalProduct> AdditionalProductsTo { get; set; }
}
```

Then in the `OnModelCreating` as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalProduct>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.Product)
                .WithMany(t => t.HisAdditionalProducts)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.ProductId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    modelBuilder.Entity<AdditionalProduct>()
                .HasRequired(m => m.AdditionalProduct)
                .WithMany(t => t.AdditionalProductsTo)
                .HasForeignKey(m => m.AdditionalProductId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `public virtual ICollection<AdditionalProduct> HisAdditionalProducts { get; set; }`

Comment: @FortyTwo You are absolutely correct! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The great solution for you is:

First, make a new class for all your `Aditional Productions`

```
[Table("AdditionalProducts")]
public class AdditionalProduct
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> AdditionalProducts { get; set; }
}
```

Second, create a `relationship` `one-to-one` to this class

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Argument> Arguments { get; set; }//your business

    public int AdditionalProductsId { get; set; }
    public virtual AdditionalProduct AdditionalProducts { get; set; }
}
```

[See more one-to-one](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Hope to be useful for you!

Comment: How will `AdditionalProducts` table be created? It is not referenced form `Product`

Comment: If you have a database active you have to create a migration! From migration, the table will be created! And is referred with one-to-one relationship

Comment: It isn't referred, `Product` refers to `Product`.

Comment: I saw! My mistake: I will edit: `public virtual Product AdditionalProducts { get; set; }` become `public virtual AdditionalProduct AdditionalProducts { get; set; }`